# Doctrine DQL: DQL Join between 4 entities

Tags: php, mysql, join, doctrine-orm, dql

So, I have this entities structure:

- `User` that has some `Email`s (more than one at the same time);
- Each `Email` that belongs to `Domain`s (if email@example.com, then I have the `Domain` "example.com` in the database)
- Each `Domain` MAY have a `Profile` linked to it.

**Now, given a `User` I'd like to get all the `Profiles` (s)he can access (IF ANY! Maybe the `Domain` doesn't have a `Profile`).**

The Entities structure:

```
// User entity
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Email", mappedBy="forUser")
     */
    protected $emails;

    ...
}


// Email entity
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Repository\EmailRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="emails")
 */
class Email
{
    /**
     * @var EmailValue
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="email", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var Domain
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Domain", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="domain", referencedColumnName="second_level")
     */
    protected $domain;

    /**
     * @var \MyNamespace\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyNamespace\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="emails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="for_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $forUser;

    ...
}


// Domain entity
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Repository\DomainRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="domains")
 */
class Domain
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $secondLevel;

    /**
     * @var UrlValue
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="uri", nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $url;

    ...

    /**
     * Each Domain can be linked to only one Profile.
     *
     * @var Profile|null
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Profile", inversedBy="domain")
     */
    private $profile;

    /**
     * Each Domain can have more than one Email.
     *
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Email", mappedBy="domain")
     */
    private $emails;

    ...
}


// Profile entity
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="profiles")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\AppBundle\Repository\ProfileRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Profile
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
     * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="AppBundle\Doctrine\IdGenerator")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Each Store can have only one Domain.
     *
     * @var Domain
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Domain", mappedBy="profile")
     */
    private $domain;

    ...
}
```

**Now, given a `User` I'd like to get all the `Profiles` (s)he can access (IF ANY! Maybe the `Domain` doesn't have a `Profile`).**

I decide if a `User` can access a `Profile` if (s)he has an `Email` with the `Domain`.

So, if the `User` has an `Email` email@example.com, (s)he can access the `Profile` of the `Domain` example.com.

**I know I need to join the four tables but I have no idea of how I can do such `JOIN`.**

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you made all your relations bidirectionals, you can perform such a query by joining tables from the `Profile` one. You could use [the query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder) and add the following method to your `ProfileRepository` to perform a search based on a `User` instance:

```
public function getUserProfiles(User $user)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('profile')
        ->addSelect('domain') // select the corresponding domain at the same time
        ->join('profile.domain', 'domain')
        ->join('domain.emails', 'emails')
        ->where('emails.forUser = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

If you simply have access to the user ID, you can use `where('IDENTITY(emails.forUser) = :userId')` instead of the `where` clause written above.

*Note: If a user have multiple emails linked to the same domain/profile, the underlying SQL query will return the same profile entry multiple times but Doctrine will collapse them to a single entry in the result set if you use `getResult` or `getArrayResult`. You will get duplicates if you use `getScalarResult` [as described in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats).*

---

You could also do this the other way around and join `emails`, `domain` and `profile` from `User` to be able to reach all the data from your `User` instance. The important part would be to use `leftJoin` for the `profile` join so that domains without profiles would still get selected. In that case, you would need to add a method to your `User` class to crawl the `emails` of the user and retrieve the corresponding profiles.